# Could not load file or assembly 'e_sqlite3

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp, sqlite-net-pcl

When I debug my UWP project I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'e_sqlite3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.'

The error occurs on this line:
`Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);`

From the following code block:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
    // just ensure that the window is active
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
        rootFrame = new Frame();

        rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);

        if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
        {
            //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
        }

        // Place the frame in the current Window
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }

    if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
    {
        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
}
```

A little background... I started out with 3 projects in my solution (Shared Library, WPF, and Android).  The application is currently reading and writing to a sqlite file in both the Android and WPF projects.

I just added the UWP project.  After adding a reference to the shared library and adding the relevant nuget packages I encounter the error when debugging the UWP project.

Here is my Current Solution:
[Screenshot of Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOXRG.jpg)

I am using SQLite-net-pcl nuget version 1.5.231 (the most current stable version at time of posting).
[Screenshot of nuget package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3sX4.jpg)

I also have the SQLiteNetExtensions and SQLiteNetExtensions.Async nuget packages.
[Screenshot of all sqlite related nuget packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYw93.jpg)

My UWP project has:
Target Version: Windows 10, version 1809
Min Version: Windows 10 Fall Creators Update
[screenshot of UWP Target settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCd5k.jpg)

I have found a number of posts regarding this issue but they all seem to indicate that this was resolved in SQLite-net-pcl version 1.5.166, and I'm using a newer version.

Another posts mentions using a sqlite extension for visual studio, which I was unable to find.  That post was a few years old so the fix might not be relevant since it's referencing Visual Studio 2015.

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2017, Version 15.9.9.  Running on a Windows 10 Pro workstation with all of the latest updates and service packs.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried SQLite-net-pcl version 1.5.166 instead of  the newer version?

Comment: I've seen this problem come and go a few times now. I still have no idea what changes to fix / unfix this. Adding SQLite-net-pcl does not help.Changing all my packages from packages.config files to project based seemed to fix it the first time i saw it. (right click option on the project to do this). BTW e_sqlite3 does exist.